# Do I need a voltage regulator to maintain a constant 12V voltage to run a 12V brushed DC motor?

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-motor

I am building an autonomous mobile robot. I am using Pololu 12V, 75:1 Metal Gear Motor (No Load Current: 300 mA, Stall Current: 5.6A), Cytron 20A Bi-Directional 6V-30V DC Motor Driver MD20A, and a Lipo battery.

I want to know whether I need a voltage regulator to maintain a constant 12V voltage.

Also, which Lipo battery will be better to run a 12v brushed DC motor? 11.1v or 14.8v?

[image]

Comment: If you have a datasheet for your motor, it will probably give some info. If you don't, then guessing is quite possible but be aware it's a guess. (other people say "datasheet or gtfo", I do not, at least for such unprofessional projects anyway)

Answer (score 1):

The motor driver should control the voltage or speed without a regulated supply. If you want to get full speed out of the motor, use the 14.8 V battery.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

The 12V is a nominal voltage and probably has a range of several volts. By not using the voltage regulator you will have that much more energy for your motor. Also since the motor draws a large amount of stall current you would need a fairly expensive regulator that will only degrade your design. The low impedance of the batteries is your best allie.  You might want to add a bypass capacitor and a bulk capacitor across the battery terminal to keep electrical noise down. The higher voltage battery will give you more power for your robot and it will also make it go faster.